# How to join a custom table and show its attribute on Magento 2 rest Api getList() function?

Tags: magento2, collection, product-collection, search-criteria

Im creating a custom product Api with searchCriteria from **\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection**

And I joined other table to this collection;

```
public function getList(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection */
    $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array("vendorProduct"=>'ced_csmarketplace_vendor_products'), 'e.entity_id = vendorProduct.product_id',array('vendor_id' => "vendor_id"));
    
    $this->extensionAttributesJoinProcessor->process($collection);

    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
    $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');

    $this->collectionProcessor->process($searchCriteria, $collection);

    $collection->load();

    $collection->addCategoryIds();
    $this->addExtensionAttributes($collection);
    $searchResult = $this->searchResultsFactory->create();
    
    $searchResult->setSearchCriteria($searchCriteria);
    $searchResult->setItems($collection->getItems());
    $searchResult->setTotalCount($collection->getSize());

   
    return $searchResult;
}
```

The joined data not show when I call this Api.

**But if I "return $collection->getData();" it will show the joined data.**

[image]

Comment: in both screenshot, I see the identical data, am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I uploaded a wrong image.

Comment: you may add your webapi.xml file and your repository function at least for us to know where you get it wrong.. Of course we can do it all from scratch but who will?

Answer (score 0):

The searchResult is the result from the repository `getList` function and you may see this function (the one that appears in your post) mentions `attributeJoinProcessor` and so on.. these lines aggregate to the collection various additional values - amongst them are `extension_attributes` - but more simply the product data that are setup to be part of this repository `getList` call.

Instead, the collection is just the product collection that you can create independently to the repository. Using the collection can be useful in many circumstances (particularly to write complex custom query). Now, of course all the extension_attributes won't appear in the collection unless you make some complex joins yourself.

Hope this gives you enough background to see why your result do differ